# c# dataBase update via adapter error

Tags: c#, .net, relational-database

I use `OleDbAdapter` and `autoUpdate` command creation:

```
`builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter);
sqlAdapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
sqlAdapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
sqlAdapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
```

`

my table has 7 columns. 6 of 7 are updates OK via
`sqlAdapter.Update();`
but 1 throws Exception

> "Syntax error in UPDATE command".

So please tell me, its correct to form update and other commands automatically?
What wrong with one column?
Thanks in advance!

there is auto generated update command
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-l-KfpcXy9nm4Phiu-1A7MirtqMfx3-5/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Post the Table definition and the generated Update command. And maybe how you set up the Adapter. Right now this is a guessing game.

Comment: SqlAdapter and OleDbCommand?  Be specific about which class types these are.

Comment: @bommelding its correct way to create commands automatically?
It is possible that auto created commands may be       wrong??
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hard to say. A lot of information is still missing here.

Comment: @bommelding please look the image in the end of main post.